# Calculating a column based partly on itself in python/pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am about 3 days into learning Pandas through Python and have come across the first issue that has me stumped. I've managed to do a variety of calculations that I need by not having to iterate through each row of the table I am processing, but I'm not sure if there is a way to do the same with the following issue.

The table that I am trying to work with could be boiled down to only 2 columns for the purposes of this issue. The first column is 'date', and the second is 'order'. The 'order' column has values of mostly 0, interspersed with a few 1 and -1. Not sure how to show that in my question but something like ...

```
         Date  Order
0  2017-03-15      0
1  2017-03-14      1
2  2017-03-13      0
3  2017-03-12      0
4  2017-03-11     -1
5  2017-03-10      0
6  2017-03-09      0
7  2017-03-08      1
```

I want add another column, called 'status' which is at first based on the 'order' column, but also on the 'status' column, depending on the value of the 'order' column.

If I was adding a formula in Excel in the status column, it would be:
=if(order = 1, 1, if(order = -1, -1, status[from row-1]))

So the resulting table would look like this:

```
         Date  Order  Status
0  2017-03-15      0       0
1  2017-03-14      1       1
2  2017-03-13      0       1
3  2017-03-12      0       1
4  2017-03-11     -1      -1
5  2017-03-10      0      -1
6  2017-03-09      0      -1
7  2017-03-08      1       1
```

The status column should end up with only 1 or -1, after the initial classification (might start with 0's until that time though). Although the order column generally alternates between 1 and -1 (aside from the interspersed 0's), it is also possible that the order column may have a 1, for example, followed by another 1 in the next row, or after a few rows, before the -1. It's an input data error that I can ignore, but the code may need to account for that.

I am currently using Pandas, but could also use numpy if necessary.

Hopefully that is clear enough. Forgive the poor formatting. And thanks for the helping hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

combination of `mask`, `ffill`, and `fillna`

```
o = df.Order
df.assign(Status=o.mask(o == 0).ffill().fillna(o).astype(int))

         Date  Order  Status
0  2017-03-15      0       0
1  2017-03-14      1       1
2  2017-03-13      0       1
3  2017-03-12      0       1
4  2017-03-11     -1      -1
5  2017-03-10      0      -1
6  2017-03-09      0      -1
7  2017-03-08      1       1
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I just tried it out and it worked great. I just had to add 'df =' in front of the second line to get the column to persist in my output. It gives me some homework now to figure out how and why it works!